# How to add custom validation code after validate.js

Tags: joomla3.0

I want to add a custom validation handler to Joomla's default client-side validation class, e.g.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
        document.formvalidator.setHandler('birth', function(value) {
        regex=/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
        return regex.test(value);
    });
});
```

I want this in a JS file for the component.  The problem I am having is that the custom handler must be defined after the validation class, so it has to appear after:

```
<script src="/media/system/js/validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I can do this by adding in the com_mycomponent/site/mycomponent.php

```
$document->addScript(...)
```

But the  declaration will appear before validate.js.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Scripts added with document object will appear where your template include is.

```
$document->addScript(...)
```

Will appear here

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

So the include should be top of page in the head

If you are including the window addEvent via addScript you will need to do it in the correct order also.

formvalidator runs native events first, so if you want to do something say before the require function runs, you're out of luck.